# QWebElement that contains text caret

Tags: qt, qwebview, qwebelement

I'm using editable `QWebView` to implement wysiwyg editor. Is it possible to get `QWebElement` that contains caret? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element by performing a hit test:

```
QWebPage webpage = ui->webView->page();

QPoint point = webpage->inputMethodQuery(Qt::ImMicroFocus).toRect().center();

QWebHitTestResult res = webpage->mainFrame()->hitTestContent(point);

QWebElement elm = res.element();
```